# Is there a way in Firebase Cloud Functions (gen 2) to get notified when the time limit is about to expire

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that is doing background work through a task queue.  Sometimes the work may take longer than the time limit for the function.  Is there a way to have the code get notified that the time is about to expire so I can close up the work and make a note to start where I left off?

Comment: I doubt if there's any such feature, but maybe you can use `setTimeout()` that triggered some notification a minute or 2 before max timeout?

Comment: @Dharmaraj That is my best thought so far too.  Should be pretty close for most cases unless something kills the process early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions Gen2 runs on Cloud Run. A container instance is not notified the **maximum request execution time** has expired (or will expire, etc.).